# UMLクラス図で、同じ型を複数の属性で集約する場合の表現

Tags: uml

下記のクラス（Javaコード）をUMLのクラス図で表現する標準的な表現ルールはありますか？

```
class Foo {
   Bar hoge;
   Bar fuga;
}
```

`Foo`→`Bar`の集約線を一本引くだけだと、`hoge`と`fuga`の2つの集約を表せません。
特に、`hoge`と`fuga`がコレクションで、多重度がそれぞれ異なる場合には困ります（`hoge`は`1:1…*`だけど、`fuga`は`1:0…*`だったり）
集約線を2本引いて、線にhogeとかfugaとかそれぞれ書くとか、オレオレルールでやろうと思えばできますが、標準的な方法があればそれに従いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[標準的な仕様](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/)かどうかは分かりませんが、このあたりを読むと、2本の集約線でよさそうですね。

- [UML: how to show a class having 2 collections of the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182664/uml-how-to-show-a-class-having-2-collections-of-the-same-class)
- [Two (or more) aggregation relationships between two entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105732/two-or-more-aggregation-relationships-between-two-entities)

IDEのいくつかのUMLプラグインでJavaのソースコードからUMLを生成してみるのも、いいかもしれません。